# Solving nonlinear system

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

I have the following nonlinear system
$$\begin{cases}
y_1 = \frac{x_1}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}} \\
y_2 = \frac{x_2}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}} \\
y_3 = \frac{x_3}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}}
\end{cases}
$$

How can I check whether it has solution for $x_1,x_2,x_3$ and whether it is unique? How do I solve it?

What if I know that $x_1=1$ and I need to solve it for $x_2,x_3$.

This question is related to:
[Injectivity of transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1383930/probability-density-on-the-sphere-and-change-of-variables)

Comment: Hint: use spherical coordinates instead of $x$'s

Comment: what are the solve variables?

Comment: I need to solve it for $x_1,x_2,x_3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, you should have
$$
y_1^2 + y_2^2 + y_3^2 = 1.
$$
Let
$$
x_1 = R\sin\theta\cos\phi,\\
x_2 = R\sin\theta\sin\phi,\\
x_3 = R\cos\theta
$$
(you always can find such $R$, $\theta$ and $\phi$; check this if you want). So,
$$
y_1 = \sin\theta\cos\phi,\\
y_2 = \sin\theta\sin\phi,\\
y_3 = \cos\theta
$$
From last you can find $\theta$. And
$$
\frac{y_2}{y_1} = \tan\phi
$$
Now you can determine $\phi$ and $\theta$ (with some annoying manipulations with signs). You cannot determine $R$ (because $y$'s doesn't change if you multiply all $x$'s by something).